# Passing values between tabs in a form in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, variables, tabs

I have a form with 3 tabs: one tab is for user entry and computations, a second tab shows values that will be used for computations which are read from one database (I call it settings in that the values are constants for calculations but it's not application settings in the way people think of it, to be clear) and the third displays a table from another database. The second tab has a table adapter interface for the dataset that contains values used for calculations that can be changed (to do different scenarios.) Those numbers are read from a single record in a database that has 20 fields and was read once when the data is loaded into the second tab to be displayed.

The problem I am having is that I would like to use the numbers from the second tab (the constants) in computations to be shown on the first tab.

I have tried declaring the variables on the second tab as public but they are already "friends" with the form event. However, when I go to use them in calculations, it's like they don't exist.

For example, one calculation I am doing is fuel cost. The user enters miles and this is stored as a variable called mileage. To calculate the result fuelcost, I have to use two other fields that are shown in the second tab: MPG (miles per gallon) and fuelprice (the price of gas). So fuelcost = (mileage/mpg)*fuelprice. These are read from a datatable called testdata which is actually part of the project. I want to be able to use these variables throughout the program but declaring them as public isn't working.

How do I make the variables from one tab usable elsewhere in the program? The other thing I noticed is since the values of the variables are loaded into textboxes and assigned variable names by naming the textboxes, using val([variablename].text) isn't solving the problem either. For example, saying milespergallon = val(mpg.text) is not doing the trick because I am getting a message that 'text' is not an integer when I declare milespergallon.

**Update**

Here the code that is being used:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mileage = Int32.Parse(Miles.Text)
    Dim rate = 0
    Dim baserate = 0
    Dim rateper = 0
    Dim ratemile As Integer
    Dim Mpg As Decimal
    Dim milespergallon As Decimal
    milespergallon = CDec(Mpg.Text)
    ' Ensure the value is numeric 
    If IsNumeric(Mpg) Then
        Mpg = CDec(Mpg)
    Else
        milespergallon = CDbl(Mpg.Text)
    End If
    txtmilespergallon.Text = milespergallon.ToString
End Sub
```

TabPage2 is where the variables are displayed that I want to use in TabPage1.

```
Private Sub TabPage2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage2.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to another post I had regarding manipulating values from a database so my answer assumes that a user has loaded data from a single row database and displayed it in a tabpage, but wants to also use that data elsewhere in the program.

While you can drag the dataset into a tabpage to be displayed, the values from the dataset have to be stored to local variables. This has to happen in the form load event after the dataadapter fill statement in order for the numbers to be used anywhere in the form:

```
  Me.TestdataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.fooDataSet.testdata)

  variable1 = Me.fooDataSet.testdata(0).variable1
  variable2 = Me.fooDataSet.testdata(0).variable2
```

and so on. In my example, the dataset is called 'foo' so it is fooDataSet. The table is called 'testdata' and is a single row table with several records. Think of an Excel sheet with one row and several columns...this is what testdata looks like. I've generically called each 'column' variablen where n is the number of the column for my example, although you would give them more meaningful names. Example:

```
  discountcost = Me.priceDataSet.pricetable(0).discountcost
  markup = Me.priceDataSet.pricetable(0).markup
```

You can then DIM those variables. In the example of discountcost and markup, you would DIM them as decimal and then could use them in calculations in any tabpage on your form.

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing preventing you from using values from a textbox in one tab in another tab.

Say for example, the textbox holding miles per gallon is mpg and is on form2, you should be able to write:

```
  Dim milesPerGallon As Decimal
  ' Ensure the value is numeric before trying to use it
  If IsNumeric(mpg.Text) Then
      milesPerGallon = CDec(mpg.Text)
  Else
      ' Do something here
  End If
```

Note that you should attempt to validate the content of the textbox before trying to convert it.

It is also very important to add the following options to the very top of your source code file:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
```

This will help if you have slightly different names for variables and don't notice it. Without option explicit on, VB will automatically create variables that are not declared, which can wreak havoc with your code.

Option strict forces the data types to be correct in your code. Without this, VB will try to automatically change variables to what it thinks the correct types are, but this isn't always correct.

Note that you can also enforce these settings for the entire project by right-clicking on the project, selecting `Properties`, clicking on the `Compile` tab, selecting `All Configurations` from the `Configuration dropdown`, and selecting `On` from the `Option explicit` and `Option strict` dropdowns.

**Update for new code in question**

Given the following code in the question:

```
    Dim Mpg As Decimal
    Dim milespergallon As Decimal
    milespergallon = CDec(Mpg.Text)
    ' Ensure the value is numeric 
    If IsNumeric(Mpg) Then
        Mpg = CDec(Mpg)
    Else
        milespergallon = CDbl(Mpg.Text)
    End If
```

There is a typo somewhere because Mpg is declared as a local variable of type Decimal, so it won't have a .Text property. I suspect that this is causing at least some problems.

Here is how I would rewrite that block of code, assuming that Mpg is the name of the textbox on tab2:

```
    Dim milespergallon As Decimal

    ' Ensure the value is numeric 
    If Not IsNumeric(Mpg.Text) Then
        milespergallon = 0
    Else
        milespergallon = CDec(Mpg.Text)
    End If
```

**Update**

Here is how I would rewrite your button click code:

```
    Dim mileage As Integer
    Dim speed As Integer

    If IsNumeric(Me.Miles.Text) Then
        mileage = CInt(Me.Miles.Text)
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Me.SpeedTextBox.Text) Then
        speed = CInt(Me.SpeedTextBox.Text)
    End If

    If speed <> 0 Then
        Traveltime = CDec(mileage / speed)
    Else
        Traveltime = 0
    End If

    txttraveltime.text = Traveltime.ToString
```

Comment: I think that you may have the assignment order backwards. I believe what you want is `milespergallon = CDec(txtMilesPergallon.text)`.

Comment: Thanks, Competent_Tech! Still having trouble. Tried the conversion method above. To test that the variable is being captured for use, I put it into a textbox on my screen and it came out as zero when the value showing in TabPage2 was 5.0. The textbox I used to do this was txtMilespergallon.text = milespergallon.tostring. Is there any reason why val([variablename].text) shouldn't work? It usually works the best and not sure why it's not this time around. I was wondering if it's because the TabPage my data seems to appear as a "Private Sub" when I look at the code and not being shared?

Comment: I'm now getting an error re: milespergallon = CDec(txtMilesPergallon.text) that says "when casting from a number, the value must be from a number less than infinity" (which it is) and also suggests "make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type." The source type is numeric in the mdb file so I'm not sure why this would get hung up :/

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you are making progress. What this error means is that txtMilesPerGallon.Text is empty (this is why I suggested using the IsNumeric function before trying to convert the value). Why it's empty is the next question. I would do a couple of things: 1) triple-check the name of the textbox in the form designer to ensure it's what you think it is (I have had cases where I copied a field and it went right over the top of the actual field) 2) Step through the code in debugger and look at the value of txtMilesPerGallon.Text at each stop. When it changes to blank, that's your problem.

Comment: Happy New Year all! Checked the names of the fields and textboxes and they are correct. I tried using the debugger by using "step into" (it's the first time I've used this) and I set up an immediate window but it shows "stepping over non-user code" and didn't show me variable values. Also, will changing the property of the textboxes containing the data I want to Public or something other than Private make my data visible in other tabs? Everything else appears to be not working and I thought that if one makes a variable Public, it's usable anywhere in the program.

Comment: If all of your code is in the same form, then having the textboxes be private would be enough. Can you edit your question and include some of the code that you are having issues with? I think that's the only way we can make any further progress on this.

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mileage = Int32.Parse(Miles.Text)
        Dim rate = 0
        Dim baserate = 0
        Dim rateper = 0
        Dim ratemile As Integer
        Dim Mpg As Decimal
        Dim milespergallon As Decimal
        milespergallon = CDec(Mpg.Text)
        ' Ensure the value is numeric 
        If IsNumeric(Mpg) Then
            Mpg = CDec(Mpg)
        Else
            milespergallon = CDbl(Mpg.Text)
        End If
        txtmilespergallon.Text = milespergallon.tostring

Comment: TabPage2 is where the variables are displayed that I want to use in TabPage1. Private Sub TabPage2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage2.Click

    End Sub

Comment: Ok, I have added your code to the question and updated the answer. As an FYI: It will be much easier for both of us, if you have more code to add, to edit the question and add it as I have done.

Comment: The problem now appears to have been reduced to "Text is not a member of Decimal" and I double checked all the variables loaded into the textboxes were loaded as data type system.decimal, which is interesting.  I've added some more code (above) about the form load event because I was starting to second guess about the textbox variables.

Comment: Hmm... Not seeing the new code, but it sounds like the same problem you had before: you are trying to use a local variable as a textbox.

Comment: Added some code for a test app I was doing to see if therw was a simple way to fetch something from one tabpage and use it on another.

Comment: Not sure why the code I pasted isn't coming up nice and formatted :S

Comment: Are you trying to edit the original question or add code in the comments? You should edit the original question and add your code there. One thing that I always do to make it absolutely clear where a variable is coming from is to prefix textboxes with `txt` (i.e. `txtMPG`). This way, you can look at the code and immediately know which code is referencing textboxes and which is referencing local variables. Then, only the textboxes should use the .Text property (i.e. `milespergallon = CDec(txtMPG.Text)`).

Comment: Yes, tried to edit the original question and put in some code from a test program I did. I don't think the nomenclature is the problem so much as how the program is recognizing what belongs to the tabpage. I just tried doing a simple program with two tabs: the first tab has a button to click and one textbox (txtfoo2) that displays the value that resides in tabpage2 (txtfoo). As simple as it is and should be, I am getting "foo is not a member of system.windows.forms.tabpage". I've tried doing like foo2 = Me.Tabpage2.txtfoo.text and that doesn't work. I'm not sure why it's not a member.

Comment: Ah, I see your issue now: the controls belong to the form, not the tab page. Yes, they are *placed* on the tab page, but they physically belong to the form. So all you need to do to reference them is `foo2 = Me.txtfoo.text`

Comment: Yep! That solved the problem. Thank you very much! I learned a lot about tabs in the meantime. I do appreciate your help! Looks like I underestimated the power of "Me" lol...(badaboom badabing!) Sorry for the lame comedy. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Keep in mind that if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the answer so that future visitors to the question will know this is what helped you out. Thanks!

Comment: Well, went back to the original program and tried it out. So good so far except now my variable appears to be mysteriously a zero value when I went to use it in a calculation. I have one text box where someone enters miles (miles.text) and the speed (me.speedtextbox.text) is stored in 'speed'. The result, traveltime=mileage/speed shows "infinity" in the answerbox, txttraveltime.text when it should be 100 miles divided by 65 mph = 1.53 hours. I posted the code above. It worked in my 'foo' test and now I'm not sure why it won't do this. I posted the code. Thanks!

Comment: Something seems to be amiss with your code posting; I cannot see any of it. Are you clicking on the `edit` link directly under the question, adding your code to the bottom of the scrollable textbox, then clicking the Save Edits button?

Comment: I see what is happening; the edits are going in for review and someone is rejecting them. I found your sample code and tried it out and it worked just fine. I made some minor edits to correct some potential issues and added them to the answer.

Comment: (I rolled back that edit as I felt that it warranted a new question; as far as I can tell the edit introduced a new question fairly unrelated to the original one. I could argue that the last edit is of a similar nature, as it answers a question which now hasn't been asked. But meh.)

Comment: Oh crap! I just posted that new question per You's suggestion. c_t, the program still thinks speed = 0. I tried putting in 65 as the mileage and I should get 1 but kept getting zero. Speed is definitely an integer and I'm baffled why it's coming out as 0. Why won't val work?